# CSS selector that matches parent of empty element

Tags: html, css

I have such HTML code

```
<li data-bind="attr: { class: MenuItem.CssClass, 'data-Id': MenuItem.Id }">
    <div class="subMenuActions">
        <i class="icon-caret-right" />
        <i class="icon-caret-down" />
    </div>
    ...
    <ul class="subMenu"></ul>
</li>
```

I want to make selector for elements `i` in `div.subMenuActions` which will check if `ul.subMenu` is empty.

I know that I can check if `ul.subMenu` is empty by using CSS selector `ul.subMenu:empty`, but I need to hide `i.icon-caret-down`, `i.icon-caret-right` if `ul.subMenu` is empty.

Please no JS answers.

Comment: This is not HTML code, because `<i>` element can't be self-closed in any way in HTML. It may be XML/XHTML code if served with appropriate `Content-type`, but if served as `text/html`, this code will be interpreted by HTML parsers as nested unclosed tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to select [previous element sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector#1817801) nor [parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector#1014958) with CSS on levels 1-3. As Mishik say, you can only select next siblings.

In your case if you reorder elements in HTML and you know the height of the `ul.submenu` element, you can use this solution:

```html
<li data-bind="attr: { class: MenuItem.CssClass, 'data-Id': MenuItem.Id }">
    <ul class="subMenu"></ul>
    <div class="subMenuActions">
        <i class="icon-caret-right"/>
        <i class="icon-caret-down"/>
    </div>
    ...
</li>
```

then apply this css:

```css
li {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:2em;
}
ul.subMenu {
    height:2em;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
div.subMenuActions {
    position:relative;
}
ul, div { /* normalize to zero */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/* and the selectors */
ul.subMenu:empty + .subMenuActions > i,
ul.subMenu:empty + .subMenuActions + .subMenuActions > i {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7VmR9/15/

All in all, much easier way here to go is to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "previous sibling" selector in CSS, unfortunately (at least for now).

I could only suggest changing the order of `.subMenu` and `.subMenuActions` and then use this:

```
.subMenu:empty + .subMenuActions > i{
    display: none;
}
```

Afterall, you can always style `.subMenuActions` to display it in the required place.

Comment: Your statements are contradictory. There is indeed no "previous sibling selector" in CSS - this actually precludes `~` being able to find *all* siblings. So your code won't work.

Comment: @BoltClock I have hidden the post right away when I realized that `~` will not work this way.